# ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation in InscriptionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to check my registrations form in rails 7 in Ubuntu 22, but it is not working as it should, and I'm still getting some error. The app should send with the POST request data to the server after filling the registrations form in.

I have to fill the registrations form to test it, but I get the following error message:

```
Started POST "/inscriptions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-06-18 15:44:51 +0200
Processing by InscriptionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "inscription"=>{"vorname"=>"Jade", "name"=>"Doe", "age"=>"13", "adress"=>"3 Marguerite Youcenar", "email"=>"jade_doe@gmail.com", "phone"=>"0768324654", "gender"=>"feminin"}, "commit"=>"Envoyer"}
  TRANSACTION (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/inscriptions_controller.rb:27:in `block in create'
  Inscription Create (11.6ms)  INSERT INTO "inscriptions" ("vorname", "name", "age", "adress", "email", "phone", "gender", "created_at", "updated_at", "club_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["vorname", "Jade"], ["name", "Doe"], ["age", "13"], ["adress", "3 Marguerite Youcenar"], ["email", "jade_doe@gmail.com"], ["phone", "0768324654"], ["gender", "feminin"], ["created_at", "2023-06-18 13:44:51.944100"], ["updated_at", "2023-06-18 13:44:51.944100"], ["club_id", nil]]
  ↳ app/controllers/inscriptions_controller.rb:27:in `block in create'
  TRANSACTION (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/inscriptions_controller.rb:27:in `block in create'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 13.0ms | Allocations: 5257)


  
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « club_id » dans la relation « inscriptions »
DETAIL:  La ligne en échec contient (15, Jade, Doe, 13, 3 Marguerite Youcenar, jade_doe@gmail.com, 0768324654, feminin, 2023-06-18 13:44:51.9441, 2023-06-18 13:44:51.9441, null).
):
```

The following image shows some of my code I use for this app
The inscription controller:

```
class InscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_inscription, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /inscriptions or /inscriptions.json
  def index
    @inscriptions = Inscription.all
  end

  # GET /inscriptions/1 or /inscriptions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /inscriptions/new
  def new
    @inscription = Inscription.new
  end

  # GET /inscriptions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /inscriptions or /inscriptions.json
  def create
    @inscription = Inscription.new(inscription_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @inscription.save
        format.html { redirect_to inscription_url(@inscription), notice: "Inscription was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @inscription }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @inscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /inscriptions/1 or /inscriptions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @inscription.update(inscription_params)
        format.html { redirect_to inscription_url(@inscription), notice: "Inscription was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @inscription }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @inscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /inscriptions/1 or /inscriptions/1.json
  def destroy
    @inscription.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to inscriptions_url, notice: "Inscription was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_inscription
      @inscription = Inscription.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def inscription_params
      params.require(:inscription).permit(:club_name, :age, :vorname, :name, :adress, :email, :phone, :gender)
    end
end
```

The model look like this:

```
class Inscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :club, :optional => true

  #validates :club_name, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
  validates :phone, presence: true , format: { with: /\A\d{10}\z/ }
end
```

The club model:

```
class Club < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ClubAdulte
  belongs_to :ClubTeevo
  belongs_to :ClubJeuneLecteur
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have `NOT NULL` constraint

Since you have `belongs_to` association with `optional: true` option, you need fix database layer by adding and executing new migration

```
def change
  change_column_null :inscriptions, :club_id, null: true
end
```